# Using requests to get an excel spreadsheet via openpyxl's virtual book (Python 3)

Tags: python, excel, encoding, request

I am currently getting an excel file via the requests module in Python. I want to take the binary object and write the contents to an excel spreadsheet like so:

```
    try:
        resp = request.post('www.restendpoint.com/rest/', data=body, stream=True)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Encountered exception: [ ", e, " ]")

    # First just try to write the content to the file
    with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(resp.content)

    # Try to loop over chunks of the data to write to the file
    with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in resp.iter_lines():
            f.write(chunk)

    # 2nd attempt to loop over the chunks of data to write to the file
    with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in resp.iter_content():
            f.write(chunk)
```

For each of those "with open" blocks, the data ends up being written to the spreadsheet without really doing what I want (which is to generate a nice beautiful spreadsheet).

For reference, here is the first cell that ends up being written:

```
b'PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00L\x82oL\x1f#\xcf\x03\xc0\x00\x00\x00\x13\x02\x00\x00\x0b\x00\x00\x00_rels/.rels\xad\x92O\x8b\xc2@\x0c\xc5\xbfJ\x99\xfb\x1aW\xc1\xc3b=y\xe9mY\xfc\x02q&\xfdC;\x93!\x13\xb1~{\x87\xbdl\xb7TP\xf0\x18^\xf2\xde\x8fG\xf6?4\xa0v\x1cR\xdb\xc5T\x8c~\x08\xa94\xadj\xfc\x02H\xb6%\x8fi\xc5\x91BVj\x16\x8f\x9aGi \xa2\xed\xb1!\xd8\xac\xd7;\x90\xa9\x879\xec\xa7\x9eE\xe5J#\x95\xfb4\xc5\t\xa5!-\xcd8\xc0\x95\xa5?3\xf7\xabl\x9b\x85[\xa4gB\xb9\xae;KG\xb6\x17OA\x17\xb2g\x1b\x06\x96Y6\x7f
```

And to compare it, here is the same chunk from the *resp.content*:

```
b'b\'PK\\x03\\x04\\x14\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x08\\x00\\x82\\x83oL\\x1f#\\xcf\\x03\\xc0\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x13\\x02\\x00\\x00\\x0b\\x00\\x00\\x00_rels/.rels\\xad\\x92O\\x8b\\xc2@\\x0c\\xc5\\xbfJ\\x99\\xfb\\x1aW\\xc1\\xc3b=y\\xe9mY\\xfc\\x02q&\\xfdC;\\x93!\\x13\\xb1~{\\x87\\xbdl\\xb7TP\\xf0\\x18^\\xf2\\xde\\x8fG\\xf6?4\\xa0v\\x1cR\\xdb\\xc5T\\x8c~\\x08\\xa94\\xadj\\xfc\\x02H\\xb6%\\x8fi\\xc5\\x91BVj\\x16\\x8f\\x9aGi \\xa2\\xed\\xb1!\\xd8\\xac\\xd7;\\x90\\xa9\\x879\\xec\\xa7\\x9eE\\xe5J#\\x95\\xfb4\\xc5\\t\\xa5!-\\xcd8\\xc0\\x95\\xa5?3\\xf7
```

And at the scene of the crime, we have our culprit. The double escape characters must be the reason I can't simply generate the spreadsheet with the easy 3 lines and this is where I am stumped.

**What I've tried**

I have tried,

```
resp.content.decode()
```

which gives me a string without one of the backslashes. Encoding it again, just returns it to the original form.

I have also tried,

```
    escaped = resp.content.decode('unicode_escape')
    print(escaped)
    escaped = escaped.replace("\\", "")
    reencode_binary = escaped.encode()
    print(reencode_binary)

    with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(reencode_binary)
```

This generates a file, but Libre can't open it. It looks how you would expect an excel file would look if you opened it in a text editor.

I'm not quite sure of any other angles to approach this problem from. I'm fairly honed in on the binary form and that it appears to be corrupted and trying to work around that.

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the (or any) URL that you've tested?

Comment: Unfortunately I can not because of IP address restrictions.

Comment: Normally a chunk size is added, e.g. `for chunk in resp.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):` but I doubt it will change the outcome.

Comment: I have tried using a chunk size, but made no difference. I am more convinced that the format the data I am receiving is in, is not what I expect it to be. I have dumped the headers and it is 'vnd.ms-excel', but I don't know enough about mime types to determine if that would even be related to my problem.